# Testing/TDDing Private Methods

Tags: testing, tdd

Yet ANOTHER post about testing private methods, but this one I hope will be a little different to the norm.

People are always wondering whether a private method should in fact be public or the functionality extracted into another class where it can be tested, or end up making other compromises.

Many programming/scripting languages off a Reflections class, so with that in mind, why can't we automate a way of making our private methods testable? For example, let's say we have a class with a private method that we want to test, surely something like this will work:

```
class ClassWeWantToTest {
    private somePrivateMethod([args, ...]) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}

class ClassWeWantToTest_TestWrapper extends ClassWeWantToTest {

    public somePrivateMethod_test([args, ...])
    {
        return this->somePrivateMethod([args, ...]);
    }
}
```

Such testing layers can be made manually and automatically in languages that allow it. There could even be a third party tool that understands the syntax, which will parse a class and generate a layer. Obviously, private methods will only be made public to the tests. In normal use, the private methods remain private.

Why hasn't it been done already? Is this a really stupid idea? I assume it is because it hasn't been done already. It would certainly help with class-clutter, where classes are just being created to help with testability. I know, it would expose the entire class, but so what? The developer knows how it works and can now test more aspects of his code without having to work blind. The developer would be able to work with the class with or without the wrapper which would give even more flexibility.

Comment: Questions that ask "Why doesn't a language support feature X" aren't a great fit for Stack Overflow. This is likely going to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is not asking about why a language doesn't support x. It doesn't even mention a specific language. I'm asking for constructive criticism and feedback on an idea that is language independent, although certain languages would support it better than others. Can you suggest a better place to post it?

Comment: Groovy was designed around this exact principle.

Comment: _why can't we automate a way of making our private methods testable_ - because programmers don't test private methods, programmers want to quickly make changes to internal logic without rewriting tests every time you add/remove parameters of private methods.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'd argue that private methods don't necessarily solely encapsulate internal logic - but all of the methods do. I find private methods are useful for helping public methods do their job. I use them to encapsulate code that I want to either re-use, yet doesn't make sense in the public API or to clean up the public methods, adding readability by encapsulating chunks of code whilst giving them meaningful and descriptive names. The less code there is between you and the thing under test, the easier it is to debug and reason about. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The issue @DanielMann brought up is about the question being an opinion-solicitation / discussion. There's no specific programming question here; rather, a request for, as you put it, "constructive criticism and feedback." That's why it's off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Many programming/scripting languages off a Reflections class, so with that in mind, why can't we automate a way of making our private methods testable?

You can, but you are putting the priorities the wrong way around.

The point of TDD is to improve your designs.  One important element of the design is that the parts that are important to test are also easy/cost-effective to test.

Writing the same spaghetti code we've always written, but with tests, misses this.

More broadly, if you have a "private" method that is complicated enough that you aren't comfortable with the risks when you are only testing the public interfaces, then that's a big hint that what you really have is a concept that is separate and distinct from that of the enclosing method/class.  Ergo, the remedy is to redesign your solution so that you can get your test probes where you want them.

You may want to review Martin Fowler on [Published methods](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf)

> There's something to be said for the public-published distinction being more important than the more common public-private distinction.